# Ruby SQL: undefined method `[]'

Tags: mysql, ruby, connection

I think I'm being stupid.

```
rc = Mysql.new('CENSORED_HOST','username','password','db')
release = rc.query('select * from wp_ribcage_releases where release_id = 1 limit 1')

puts release["release_title"]

rc.close
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
ribcage-connect.rb:17: undefined method `[]' for #<Mysql::Result:0x1011ee900> (NoMethodError)
```

I'm new to this and I am sure I am basically doing something very stupid. Thanks a lot.

EDIT

The kind people below have got me a but further, now I have:

```
rc = Mysql.new('server','user','pword','db')

release = rc.query('select * from wp_ribcage_releases where release_id = 1 limit 1')

row = release.fetch_row
puts row['release_title']

rc.close
```

And now I get the error:

```
ribcage-connect.rb:12:in `[]': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)
    from ribcage-connect.rb:12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `rc.query(...)` returns a result set you can iterate. You can't directly access it.

Look at:

http://www.kitebird.com/articles/ruby-mysql.html#TOC_7

Since you have only one row (because of LIMIT 1) you can do:

```
row = release.fetch_hash
puts row['release_title']
```

If you have multiple rows:

```
while row = release.fetch_hash do
 puts row["release_title"]
end
```

Comment: I not getting this problem - release = rc.query('select * from wp_ribcage_releases where release_id = 1 limit 1')
release = release.fetch_row

puts release['release_artist'] = can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)
 from ribcage-connect.rb:12

Comment: @The Warm Jets: It's fetch_hash if you want to use column names. fetch_row will use column indexes. Also, you should use a different variable instead of overwriting release, for clarity.

Comment: @sled: You have a bug in your first sample, it should be fetch_hash

Answer (score 0):

That error means you cannot index directly (use []) the Result object.

It should instead be (for this single row case):

```
row = release.fetch_hash
puts row["release_title"]
```

For more information: [go here](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/ruby-mysql.html)